# What transcription to reflect Hebrew script and phonetics?

Tags: phonetics, transcription, hebrew

I am currently learning modern Hebrew with simple material (Teach Yourself Hebrew). I would like to use a different transcription than the one offered in this book or in [Omniglot](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/hebrew.htm) to build up my vocabulary lists.

In the above sources, different transcriptions are provided for the alternative pronunciations of the letters *bet (b/v), kaf (k/kh), pe (p/f)* and *shin (s/sh)*.

However I would like to use a transcription that reflects the use of a single letter+diacritic to denote the change from fricative to plosive and from alveolar to post-alveolar for *shin*.

For instance I am currently using:

- *bet*: v = [v] and ṿ [b]
- *kaf*: k = [x] and ḳ [k]
- *shin*: s = [s] and ṣ [ʃ]

I am not really satisfied however with what I have (the dot below usually denotes a retroflex and there I cannot add a dot below *f* with the international keyboard), and I would like to find a way to use the same base letter for both alternative phonetics. Could you suggest any transcription that would reflect the alternative pronunciations in a linguistically appropriate way? (It should also be easy enough to type with an international keyboard).

Comment: I took a Hebrew class once. Out teacher suggested to not use transcriptions at all, because we'd have to learn Hebrew letters anyway, and transcribing rather than reading Hebrew would deprive us of practise. To clarify pronunciation, there are alyways [matres lectionis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matres_lectionis). Maybe the answer to your question is to do without transcriptions?

Comment: I use the Hebrew script without diacritics to render vowels and moreover the keyboard I use does not provide the "dotted" *bet* etc. To render the pronunciation I think that the transcription is best and I want this transcription to respect the abugida's use of a single letter for two related sounds. Thanks.

Comment: That explains why you were using odd transcriptions in the other question. Please don't. Either use a phonetic transcription of Ivrit, or a historical transcription: using your own idiosyncratic transcription in questions on a site such as this is confusing and impolite.

Comment: @ColinFine: I was trained with Sanskrit and there are many official transcription for that language. I assumed there are many transcriptions for Hebrew. If you can refer me to a list of existing transcriptions I'll be grateful. I don't see however how finding or forging an appropriate tool for learning may appear impolite to you. In any case I can assert I don't mean to be rude.

Comment: Most transliteration of Modern Hebrew that I've seen is phonetic, so they don't attempt to distinguish ט from ת from תּ, or ס from שׂ, or כ from ח.  West European Hebraicists seem to prefer a systematic transliteration more like the one you have adopted, writing vet as 'bh' or ḅ for example. What I meant about impolite is that you are requiring people to penetrate your personal notation in order to be able to make sense of your question.

Answer (score 1):

A commenter to your post suggested that you not use transcriptions, and I would like to expand upon that.

As Hebrew words are very dependant upon the root (שורש) of the word, you will need to know the root of a word to know its meaning. Also, new words are easy to understand if you are familiar with the root. Hebrew words fall into a finite number of buildings (בניינים) that let you pick out the roots very easily. You will loose that advantage if you transcribe. Also you might loose the difference between differing letters with similar sound, such as וו and ב, for instance the words שבה and שווה would be pronounced the same but have different meanings.

For what reason do you want to use transcriptions? I may be able to help devise a plan based on your goal.

Comment: Thanks. I learn words with the script though not using diacritics. Hence I learn חושב as the 1st person singular present of חשב . As a reminder of the pronunciation "xośev" I want to add a transcription to my lexicon.

Comment: Benjamin, you're doing it wrong! :) Not using diacritics does not mean throwing out all the "vowels", such as ו or י. The 1st person present of "to think" is חובש and if you need to remember the pronunciation then it is חוֹשֵב. But you should be learning the infinitive לחשוב or with pronunciation לָחשוֹב and by knowing the building (בניין) Pa'al (פעל) you can then infer חושב for the first person singular. In other words, learn: 1) the buildings, 2) the infinitive for each word, and 3) the exceptions. Note that לחשוב has a Pa'al exception because of the leading ח.

Comment: OK. This confuses me. First of, I have no idea what a בניין is. Although if that allows me to infer the non-written vowels (i.e. E in xośEv), then I want to know. Please provide some reference? (Or I perhaps should post another question in this regard). Second, the problem is not solved (I believe) since, when I am filling up my flash-card software, I don't want depend on a system of induction to find out whether my answer is correct or wrong. I will still need a transliteration to check my answer.

Comment: Are you using Anki? That is my preferred flashcard software. There are a few Hebrew בניינים, I just googled for "hebrew binyanim" and found tons of info. I suggest learning Pa'al first, it is the most common. Know that the name of the buildings are determined by the male singular second person past tense of the letters פ ע ל in each building. So you know that the building Pa'al would have a last tense of those letters פָעָל and a last tense of ח ש ב as חְָשָב which you already know.

Comment: Yes I am using Anki and working on making another software too. Will look up info about binyanim.

Comment: PS: From what I can read of the binyanim, it does not allow me to infer the vowels in *mekhAkEś, yAśEn, mArgIś or śOtEh*. That still leaves me with a need for a transcription.

Comment: I have no idea what those words that you wrote are! The idea of a building is that there is a fixed form for the vowels and other non-root letters in the word. You just fill in the root. So you could learn one word, with vowels, in each binyaan and then you know how to pronounce all the others. For instance, if you know that לִכתוֹב is to write, and that the present tense is כוֹתֵב, then when you learn לקרוא you know to pronounce it לִקרוֹא and that the present tense is קורא, pronounced קוֹרֵא.

Comment: OK I am going to post another question regarding rules for vowel fill-in. Thanks.